# Monitoring total size of disk access of a process in Linux

Tags: linux, profiling

By giving a PID, is there any tools to record the total size of disk access within a period of time ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853655/in-linux-how-to-tell-how-much-memory-processes-are-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these Linux commands [pidstat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pidstat), [iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat),  [iotop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop). Also you can find quickly at `/proc/<PID>/io`.

Comment: Thanks that's what i need